# How to prove that the nullities of powers of a nilpotent matrix are not equal?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A$ be a nilpotent matrix of order $n$ . Prove that if $A^m \neq 0$, where $m \in \Bbb Z^{+}$, then the nullity of $A^m$ is smaller than the nullity of $A^{m+1}$.

I understand the following are the thought process:

Prove that the nullspace of $A^m$ is contained in the nullspace of $A^{m+1}$,

--> Do we use linear independence?

then prove that they are not equal.

--> Which theory can be used?

Since $A^m \neq 0$, there exists $u \in \Bbb R^n$ such that $A^m u \neq 0$. Then select a proper vector from
$$A^m u, A^{m+1}u, A^{m+2}u,\dots$$
which is in the nullspace of $A^{m+1}$ but is not in the nullspace of $A^m$.

--> I don't really understand how to do this?

Comment: The fact that $N(A^m)\subset N(A^{m+1})$ holds in general for every square matrix. For the rest, right, choose some $u$ such that $A^mu\neq 0$. Then choose the smallest $k$ such that $A^{m+k}u = 0$. Put $v := A^{k-1}u$...

Comment: It's not clear to me why this question was downvoted.  Original formatting aside, it presents the question along with the asker's relevant thoughts and attempts.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, the nullity of a matrix is the dimension of its kernel (AKA nullspace).  We see that $\ker(A^{m + 1}) \subseteq \ker(A^m)$ for **any** matrix $A$ by noting that if a vector $x$ is such that $A^mx = 0$, then we must have
$$
A^{m+1}x = A(A^mx) = A(0) = 0
$$
So, if $x$ is in the nullspace of $A^m$, then it must also be in the nullspace of $A^{m+1}$.

Now, we have to use the nilpotent propterty to prove that $\ker(A^{m+1}) \neq \ker (A^m)$.  From there, we can use the fact that $\ker(A^{m+1}) \subsetneq \ker (A^m)$ to conclude that $\dim \ker (A^{m+1}) \lneq \dim \ker(A^m)$.  That is, we will be able to conclude that the nullity of $A^{m+1}$ is less than that of $A^m$.

---

Now, let's follow their hint: we know that $A^m \neq 0$, so there is a vector $u$ such that $A^m u  \neq 0$.  However, $A^nu = 0$, so we know that we must be able to find a $k$ with $1 \leq  k \leq n-k$ such that $A^{m+k}u = 0$, but $A^{m+k-1}u \neq 0$.

Look the list of vectors $A^mu,A^{m+1}u,A^{m+2}u,\dots$ and think about why the above is true. It should be "obvious".

Once we have established that this is the case, I claim that $A^{k-1}u$ is in the nullspace of $A^{m+1}$ **but not** in the null space of $A^m$ (by definition, $A^0u = u$).  To see this, note that
$$
A^{m}(A^{k-1}u) = A^{m + k - 1}u \neq 0\\
A^{m+1}(A^{k-1}u) = A^{m+k}u = 0
$$
Now, we've shown that $\ker(A^{m+1}) \neq \ker (A^m)$.  But, with what I said earlier, the proof is complete.

Comment: Thank you so much! How can I actually use nilpotent property to prove that ker(Am+1)≠ker(Am), because what I did initially is Am+1x=A(Amx)≠Amx since Am≠0 then A≠0

Comment: Please try to format your questions and comments using MathJax, as is explained [on this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: In any case, I'm not sure what exactly you're saying that you did.  Remember, however, that $A \neq 0$ does not let you automatically say that $Au \neq 0$.  Also, just because $A^{m+1} \neq A^m$, doesn't mean that $A^{m+1}x \neq A^mx$.

Comment: So now I changed to A= 0 since A only have 0 eigenvalue, but I not sure how it will impact  $A^{m+1}$ such that $$A^{m+1} u ≠ A^m u$$

Comment: $A$ is **not** necessarily the $0$ transformation!  It is not always true that $A = 0$ if $A$ is nilpotent.  For example,
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}
$$
is nilpotent but not zero.

Comment: I think I understand your proof, I was trying if there is a simplier way to prove ahaha! I have 1 more qns, How can I prove that $A^n=0$, using the above prove by contradiction and that A is nilpotent?

Comment: Why are you trying to "prove" that $A^n = 0$?  "$A$ is a nilpotent of order $n$" **means** that $A^n = 0$ (and that $A^{n-1} \neq 0)$.

Comment: You're showing a worrying lack of understand of the basic ideas at work here.  You should consider going over the homework with the professor or teaching assistant to your course, if you're taking this course in university.

Comment: The question in particular ask for us to prove by contradiction using the above prove instead of using the nilpotent property to straight away get $A^n=0$ . Then I got stuck because its a bit hard.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking me now.  It does not look like your last comment has anything to do with this question that I just answered.