# How to prove that a certain nilpotent matrix has nullity of 1?

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ is a nilpotent matrix in $\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$, given that $A^{n-1} \neq 0 $, how to prove that the nullity of $A$ is $1$?

I do know the claim that
$$\{0 \} \subsetneq \ker(A) \subsetneq \ker(A^2) \subsetneq,\dots,\subsetneq \ker(A^{n-1}) \subsetneq \ker(A^n) = \mathbb{C}^n$$
under the given conditions. But I do not know how to prove $\ker(A^k) \subsetneq \ker(A^{k+1})$ for $k < n$.

Besides, Can we find a $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$ such that $x,Ax,...,A^{n-1}$ span $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: Use the Jordan Canonical Form!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the sequence of subspaces
$$(0) = \ker A^0\subset \ker A^1 \subset \ldots \subset \ker A^n \subset  \ldots \subset \mathbb{C}^n$$

Note that we have $\ker A^{k+1} = A^{-1}(\ker A^k)$. So every subspace in this sequence depends in the same way on the preceding one. Therefore, if $\ker A^l = \ker A^{l+1}$ for some $l$, then the sequence is stationary from that point on. Notice that $A^N= 0$ for some $N$ so the sequence stabilizes to $\mathbb{C}^n$ at some point. Therefore, the sequence increases up to a point, and then constant $\mathbb{C}^n$. The stabilization has to occur at the latest at step $n$. Otherwise, the sequence of dimensions would increase from $0$ at least $n+1$ times by at least $1$, not possible. Now, since it does not stabilize at $n-1$ (as stated), then it does at $n$, and all the dimension jumps up to that have to be $1$. So $\dim \ker A^k = k$ for $0 \le k \le n$.

Since $\dim \ker A^{n-1} = n-1$, there exists $x$ so that $A^{n-1} x \ne 0$. Let us show that $A^k x$, for $0\le k \le n-1$ form a basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$. It is enough to show linear independence. Assume that we have $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a_k A^k x = 0$, with not all $a_k=0$. Take $s$ smallest so that $a_s \ne 0$. Multiply the equality by $A^{n-1- s}$. We get $$a_s A^{n-1} x +( a_{s+1} A^n x + \cdot )= 0$$
However, all the next after first terms are $0$. We get $a_s A^{n-1} x = 0$ and so $a_s=0$, contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** (without Jordan form) Show that if $A$ is nilpotent with order $n$, then 
$$
\{0\} = \operatorname{image}(A^n) \subsetneq \operatorname{image}(A^{n-1}) \subsetneq \cdots \subsetneq \operatorname{image}(A) \subsetneq \Bbb C^n
$$
Now, consider the dimension of these spaces.

Comment: Thanks. I do know how to prove $\subseteq$. But I don't know how to get $\subsetneq$.

Comment: I get the answer from https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2214247/484838

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\ker(A^k)=\ker(A^{k+1})$, for $k<n$. Take $v$ with $A^{n-1}v\ne0$. Then
$$
0=A^nv=A^{k+1}(A^{n-k-1}v)
$$
so $w=A^{n-k-1}v\in\ker(A^{k+1})$. Therefore $A^kw=0$, which implies
$$
0=A^kw=A^k(A^{n-k-1}v)=A^{n-1}v
$$
Contradiction.